# Force figure placement in text doesn't work in 'gji' document class

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a problem with placing the figure. It is placed differently than in the code. In the `article` document class I use `[h]` specifier from the `float` package, but in the `gji` class it doesn't work. (The file `gji.cls` is available online at [this website](https://academic.oup.com/gji/pages/general_instructions); scroll to the paragraph that begins with "LaTeX Class File and Documentation" and click on the link 'gji-latex.zip' to download the zip file.) I also tried the way with `minipage`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{gji}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Theoretical fundamentals of the mechanism of electromagnetic field emission from rock samples subjected to destructive axial load are presented. The paper describes the construction of a measuring system designed for testing the nature of electromagnetic emission from rock samples subjected to axial load, giving the sensitivity of receivers required for recording weak electrical and magnetic signals. Time courses and spectra of electromagnetic fields emitted from selected rock samples, such as hard coal, sandstone, dolomite and magnesite, under conditions of destructive load on the studied objects were presented. These studies can be used to develop and implement an early warning system for mine bumps, rock formation break downs and landslide movements.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\section{The mechanism of electromagnetic emission from rock samples under load}

...

We can express (Plewa and Plewa 1992):
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
\vec{P}=Z_p\cdot d_p+\varepsilon_0\cdot \chi_r\cdot\vec{E}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
e_s=Z_p\cdot s+d_p\cdot\vec{E}
\end{equation}
where:\\

...


The process of emission of electromagnetic fields, mainly from rocks without quartz crystals in their structure, which include, among others, hard coal, is explained on the example of a network of micro-cracks formed under the influence of compressive force, whose fractures are performed by oscillatory vibrations (Gong et al 2006, Krumbholz et al 2012, Rabinovitch et al 2000, Rabinovitch et al 2003, Rabinovitch et al 2007). This mechanism concerns micro-cracks of sizes from hundredths to several millimetres (Takeuchi and Nagahama 2006). An electric diagram of a single micro-crack is shown in figure 1 (Koktavy and Sikula 2004). As you can see, the system is composed of a capacitor with a capacity of C, the covers of which perform vibrations damped around the stable position $d$. One cover is grounded and the other one is loaded with
resistance $R$.\\

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,keepaspectratio]{fig/fig1}
\caption{Electrical schematics of micro-cracks (Koktavy and Sikula 2004)}
\end{figure}

Assuming that the edges of micro-cracks are endowed with an heteronymous electrical charge (Sharma et al 2018) and starting from the law of conservation of energy, we can write (Koktavy and Sikula 2004) for the micro-cracks formed in the rock structure:
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: You should really drop the nasty habit of ending paragraphs with `\\` line-break directives.

Comment: `[h]` is a standard option not from the float package (you intended `[H]`) . As the main effect of using `[h]` is to prevent page and bottom floats, its most likely result is always to send a float to the end of the document.

Comment: The class redefines floats so `[H]` will not work. As the only reason to use a publisher class is to remove choice from the author and enforce the publisher style then i would simply allow the float to float to the top of the column as the style intends.

Comment: What I need to modify to be able to use [h] option?

Comment: `h` could be used as far as I can see, it is `[H]` that your image shows does not work.

Comment: h also doesn't work

Comment: @Mico Can you explain?

Comment: @bartzmc - If you look at the log file, you will probably find warnings where the pointless double backslashes occur, about LaTeX not being able to do a line break. To TeX, an empty line signals the end of a paragraph and causes a line break. A double-backslash does *not* terminate a paragraph; it only forces a line break. Inserting double-backslashes in those places is not only not necessary (but does smack of OCD...), it actually carries the risk of interfering with TeX's paragraph-building algorithm. Since this habit does no good and can potentially cause harm, I'd get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct it. Can you help with float this figure?

Comment: The `gji` document class was last updated more than 20 years ago. As David Carlisle has already noted in a comment, the document class file applies extensive modifications to the way LaTeX normally handles and places floats. Undoing this work, just so you can start using the `[H]` placement specifier, is unlikely to elicit applause from the editorial staff of the journal to which you are considering submitting a paper. The upshot: Let the journal have it their way, as far as the placement of `figure` and `table` floats is concerned -- and don't use `[H]` or `[h]`.

Comment: I also have more figures that should be in the middle of the document but have been moved to the end after the bibliography. I need to change this floating.

Comment: Ensure you are using the newer  well established 10 year old template I have no problem following the enclosed instructions which add a figure to keep it exactly as the class instructions intended i.e. Figure 2 is at TOP of its column, otherwise I would need to ask the journal to change their House publication style to suite my mood!

Comment: **Look exactly where the images are placed** in this published article https://academic.oup.com/gji/article-pdf/198/2/1081/1645982/ggu189.pdf